# Bootable educational cd, in Spanish, for use in library

Tags: bootable-media

Does anyone know a good live/bootable educational cd, in Spanish?
This is for use in a library in Mexico for children around 5-12 years of age.
The computer unfortunately does not have a hard drive, so installation is not
an option and need to run off a cd.

Answer (score 2):

While I have never used [Edubuntu](http://edubuntu.org/), I use Ubuntu for everything, have almost completely replaced everything else for my entire family. I have often run it off a Live CD to show other people or to browse safely in public places on other peoples computers. I believe it would be worth giving [Edubuntu](http://edubuntu.org/) a try since the only cost is the time to download and a little learning. You can start it in Spanish, though here again I have no experience with languages other than English.

Comment: Thanks!  Actually I checked out Edubuntu but it comes as an add-on cd, and requires Ubuntu already installed.  Unfortunately, the box I am working with does not have a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be referring to something like this -- [MAX](http://www.educa.madrid.org/web/madrid_linux/).
**MAX** is an educational Knoppix 3.3 based LiveCD distribution.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I'm looking at [Qimo](http://www.qimo4kids.com/default.aspx) - it looks very simple to use and has a choice to set the language to Spanish when booting up.  It's got TuxTyping, TuxMath, and some others.  Looking good so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is a derivative of Puppy Linux being translated at present. Hansamben.
It has Gcompris, tux-type, tuxmath, tuxpaint with stamps, Abiword etc
 The size of the ISO in English is 208mb, then there are add-ons. In Spanish its 200mb.

Its WIP. The help files are taking some time, so it will probably be uploaded as an Alpha soon.